# Change table name in mysql with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I need to rename a table mapped in hibernate using the JPA annotations (@Entity).
If I rename the table, Hibernate will create a new table, so I wrote a script on flyway (https://flywaydb.org/) that drop it and rename the old to the new one.

The problem is, if I run this script twice, it will drop the database renamed, losing all data. I want to write something like this

```
DROP TABLE 'NEW_TABLE' IF 'OLD_TABLE' EXISTS;
RENAME TABLE 'OLD_TABLE' TO 'NEW_TABLE';
```

I don't know how to do this in MySql, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly then Create a new table with name newName and execute the below statement. What it does is it swipes the table name and do that externally in your database and then change the name of your entity to newName. Only after that proceed to running your project.
this should work for you:

```
RENAME TABLE `oldName` TO `newName`
```

Comment: If the newName is not dropped, this will give an error "Table 'newName' already exists". Hibernate will necessarily create the table (empty) before the script runs

Comment: I have edited my answer, please try my solution and it should work.